# Generate multiple output tokens from a single input token in Amazon Style Dictionary

Tags: sass, style-dictionary

I am using Amazon Style Dictionary to generate SCSS variables from JS definition files. Given the following input:

```
module.exports = {
  color: {
    border: {
      focus: { value: '#0071ff' }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to generate not one output variable for this, but two (HEX and RGB). Is it possible to write a custom value transformer that spits out multiple values for a given input? Or do I need to run a separate pipeline for this use case?

Answer (score 0):

This could be your `colors.json` file configuration

```
  "source": ["sources/colors.js"],
  "platforms": {
    "css-rgb": {
      "transforms": ["color/rgb"],
      "buildPath": "dist/rgb/",
      "files": [
        {
          "destination": "colors-rgb.css",
          "format": "css/variables"
        }
      ]
    },
    "css-hex": {
      "transforms": ["color/hex"],
      "buildPath": "dist/hex/",
      "files": [
        {
          "destination": "colors-hex.css",
          "format": "css/variables"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

to provide to your StyleDictionary configuration.

So you grab the sources from your `sources/colors.js` file and create in output in the `dist` folder two subfolders, `rgb` containing `colors-rgb.css` and `hex` containing `colors-hex.css`.

Comment: Not exactly, what I meant as I dont want to double all tokens but only generate 2-3 for some of them.

Comment: Mapping is one on one, the only thing you can do is still using two platforms (as in the example I showed you) and for the design tokens you want to duplicate with different values, use maybe a `filter` so your output will be just with the required ones.